# match vs charmatch when used on a character vector

Tags: r, string, match

The documentation for `match` and `charmatch` seem almost identical. When used on a character vector, do they have any differences?

Comment: `charmatch` also does a partial match while `match` doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `charmatch` can also match partial in addition to `fixed` match while `match` does only a fixed match.  According to `?charmatch`

> Exact matches are preferred to partial matches (those where the value to be matched has an exact match to the initial part of the target, but the target is longer).
>
> If there is a single exact match or no exact match and a unique partial match then the index of the matching value is returned; if multiple exact or multiple partial matches are found then 0 is returned and if no match is found then nomatch is returned.

---

As an example

```
charmatch('hell', c('hello', 'hellya'))
#[1] 0
charmatch('hell', c('hello', 'hel'))
#[1] 1
charmatch('hell', c('hello', 'hell'))
#[1] 2

match('hell', c('hello', 'hellya'))
#[1] NA
match('hell', c('hello', 'hel'))
#[1] NA
match('hell', c('hello', 'hell'))
#[1] 2
```